# how to add data to the existing database in a firebase realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

my code:

```
lateadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            String anahtar=databaseReference.getKey().toString();
            final String kisiId = user.getUid().toString().trim();
            final String kisiAd = user.getDisplayName().toString().trim();
            final String yayinlananYorum = edituruneYorumyap.getText().toString();

            List<Urun> urunListesi = new ArrayList<>();
            Urun urunler = new Urun(kisiId, kisiAd, yayinlananYorum, urununAdi.getText().toString());
            urunListesi.add(urunler);
            String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();
            databaseReference.child(anahtar).child("urunYorum").setValue(urunler);


        }
    });
```

databaseReference.child(anahtar).child("urunYorum").setValue(urunler);
->i think i need a change here but i don't know.

I want to add data to the child's pre-existing reference.

when I run this encoding, it creates a new reference. Unfortunately, it adds a new record.
How can I fix?

Comment: This line `String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();` creates a new unique reference, that you then write to. If you want to write to an existing reference, you'll need to know the key of that reference, typically by reading it from the UI item tht the user clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for your help Good work. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `String key = databaseReference.push().getKey();` creates a new unique reference, that you then write to. If you want to write to an existing reference, you'll need to know the key of that reference, typically by reading it from the UI item that the user clicked on.

Note that calling `setValue()` replaces all data at the location. If you want to update a subset of the data, or add new properties, you will either have to call `setValue()` on a lower level, or call `updateChildren()`.

So for example:

```
databaseReference.child(anahtar).child("urunYorum/newProperty").setValue(urunler);
```

Or:

```
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<String,Object>();
values.put("kisiId", kisiId);
values.put("kisiAd", kisiAd);
databaseReference.child(anahtar).child("urunYorum").updateChildren(values);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was. Good work @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: but this time I have another question. In my realtime database, I have a model named "Kullanici" and  its child also my Map model. How can I retrieve data from a realtime database? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I wrote in a more understandable way. can you check ? Thanks. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: That seems like a new question. Please follow the rules of Stack Overflow, and limit to one question per post. Also: don't post additional information as an answer as you've done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784165). Stack Overflow is not a regular forum, and it works best if you follow its unique rules.

Comment: I understand, I'm new to the site I've registered, I can't use much. Thank you for your comments. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 0):

This is an improvement to @Frank van Puffelen's answer. The path "anahtar" already exists, it'll be better if you just append it like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("anahtar/urunYorum/newProperty").setValue(urunler);
```