# Firebase Database Push function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an assessment test using Android Studio and Firebase. I am pushing the entries in the first activity and update the scores after the second activity. What I want to do next is that after I am done with the two activities, once I start the first activity again, it will be pushed to a different table and be able to update that set of data again in the next activity. I can only do one assessment test, I can't record the retries, it will just update the first activity.

Query for first activity:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());

UserHistory userHistory = new UserHistory();
userHistory.setAnx(anx);
userHistory.setDep(dep);
myRef.setValue(userHistory);
```

Query for second activity

```
final DatabaseReference myRef = 
firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserHistory userHistory = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserHistory.class);
            anxHistory = userHistory.getAnx();
            depHistory = userHistory.getDep();
            anxValue = anxHistory + anx;
            depValue = depHistory + dep;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(Part2.this, databaseError.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());

            UserHistory userHistoryNew = new UserHistory();
            userHistoryNew.setAnx(anx);
            userHistoryNew.setDep(depValue);
            myRef.setValue(userHistoryNew);
```

How will I be able to write and update the next set of data without replacing the first one?

Comment: If you want to add a new set of data, consider using `myRef.push().setValue(userHistoryNew)`. If you want to update the existing data, have a look at `myRef.updateChildren()` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53769224/how-to-add-data-to-the-existing-database-in-a-firebase-realtime-database/53782463#53782463

Comment: I see, but what I'm asking is how can I retrieve the value of the myRef.push().setValue(userHistoryNew) in the next activity and update it using a button? I can't use the myRef.updateChildren() because I'm entering int values and I think that the code above only applies to String? if I use setValue, the second activity will just crash and won't update the database. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a error message with a stack trace in the logcat output. Find those and add them to your question, to improve the chance that someone spots what's going wrong.